# What is keyboard International1 in "Universal Serial Bus HID Usage Tables"

Tags: keyboard

I have an exercise where I'm given a .pcap file that was captured from a USB keyboard, and I have to give back the original string that was typed on that keyboard.

Every thing works great, and I almost got all the sentence. but when mapping, I meet this value in `0200870000000000`. When I looked in the "Universal Serial Bus HID Usage Tables" I saw that that key represent `keyboard international1` but I looked for an hour in the internet and I have no idea what letter that key represents and how to write it down.

[image]

Can any one tell what does that key represents in the keyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check footnotes 15 and 28.

> [image]
>
> **28:** Keyboard International1 should be identified via footnote as the appropriate usage for the Brazilian forward-slash (/) and question-mark (?) key. This usage should also be renamed to either "Keyboard Non-US / and ?" or to "Keyboard International1" now that it's become clear that it does not only apply to Kanji keyboards anymore.

Additionally, International1 has the "Typical AT-101 Position" of 56, which we can [find a key map](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_61/com.ibm.aix.keyboardtechref/doc/kybdtech/Key.htm) to show where is this key.

> [image]

---

On Brazilian keyboard, Internation1 is just the <kbd>/</kbd> key. The original key is used for the <kbd>;</kbd> key.

> [image]

On the PC-98 or DOS/V-109 Japanese keyboard, the key is used for entering the kana [<kbd>ろ</kbd> (ro)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ro_(kana)).

> [image]

Comment: New link to the IBM AIX Keyboard Technical Reference https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ssw_aix_73/navigation/kybdtech.pdf

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://gist.github.com/MightyPork/6da26e382a7ad91b5496ee55fdc73db2) it means:

`KEY_RO 0x87 // Keyboard International 1`

Comment: And what is that key ??

Comment: That key would be 'RO' and I would imagine it's only on International keyboards